# How to update a list of integers contained inside of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am attempting to create a hangman bot which goes through the entirety of the English language and counts each word of the same length, character by character. The idea is that the bot will return the most frequently used characters of x length at y indices. So far, I have successfully managed to import all words into a list, and filter that list to only words of x length. Where I seem to be having trouble is updating the y indices.

To accomplish this task, I have created a dictionary which stores lists as key values inside of this dictionary. ALL of the indices for the length of the word have been initialized to 0. The idea is that I would go across the entire length of the word for all words and count the occurrence of a character at a specific index. So my dictionary actually looks something like:

```
D = {'a': [0, 0, …, 0], 'b':[0, 0, …, 0], …, 'z': [0, 0, …, 0]}
```

And what I wish to do is to update each key and the index of each key so that I can find the total occurrence of all letters of the same length at that specific index. The final result would resemble the following:

```
D = {'a': [4137, 568, …, 897], …., 'z':[523, 129, … , 321]}
```

My current solution is attempting to map the indices to the keys, and increase each of the indices, but I receive the following error message:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I know this was a mouthful, but I greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you for your time and patience.

```
def occurence_of_characters(L, word):
    length_word = len(word)

    letters = string.ascii_letters
    numbers = string.digits
    characters = letters + numbers + "-" + "."
    characterlist = list(characters)

    D = {i:[0 for j in range(length_word)] for i in characterlist}
    #0 for j in range(length_word)
    for word in L:
        for key in D:
            #l = D.get(key)
            if key in word:
                for index in key:
                    D[key][int(index)] = list(map(map(lambda index: index+1, D[key][index]), D[key] ))
    print(D)
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a bit unclear, please provide an example input and output (of course, for a limited set of words.)

Comment: What is the variable `L` do? Also, please shorten the explanation and give us more information (like @lorg said)

Comment: I want to take a list of English words like: mark, cats, dogs, zips, rats. I want to count the occurrence of each character at each index. Based on the words above, my return statement would look something like: D = {'a' : [0, 3, 0, 0], …, 's': [0, 0, 0, 4], …, 'z': [1, 0, 0, 0]}

Comment: L is a list of words of the same length. I'm importing it from another function. This works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def occurence_of_characters(word_list):
    length_word = len(word_list[0])
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '.-'
    counts = {c:[0]*length_word for c in characters}
    for word in word_list:
        for i, c in enumerate(word):
            if c in counts:
                counts[c][i] += 1
    return counts


my_list = ['mark', 'cats', 'dogs', 'zips', 'rats']
D = occurence_of_characters(my_list)
for c in 'atsz':
    print(f'{c}: {D[c]}')
```

**Output:**

```
a: [0, 3, 0, 0]
t: [0, 0, 2, 0]
s: [0, 0, 0, 4]
z: [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: What is happening in the line(s): for i, c in enumerate(word):. What is the significance of enumerate(word)? Additionally, why do we do "I, c in enumerate(word)". What does this actually do? I was able to get counts[c][i] += 1 working. It does generate the above. I just would like to understand the logic behind it. Thank you

Comment: `enumerate(iterable)` takes an iterable (a string in this case) and returns another iterable where each item is a tuple consisting of an index, and the item in the original iterable. So  `enumerate("star")` say will return an iterable with items `(0, "s")`, `(1, "t")`, `(2, "a")`, `(3, "r")`. `for i, c in enumerate(word)` will then iterate over these items and assign the first element of each of the tuples to `i` and the second one to `c`.